# Is there a @NotNull annotation for Ebean in Play Framework?

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, annotations, ebean

I want Ebean in Play Framework to make some columns in my tables 'not null'. Is it possible to the `@NotNull` annotation? If yes, which package should I import? I tried with `import com.avaje.ebean.validation.NotNull;` but I got an error saying this package can't be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed `com.avaje.ebean.validation.NotNull;`

check this topic for solution:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/azlPQ14XJ2I/tdOKUkYVAxAJ

BTW:

You need to use `@Column(nullable = false)` annotation if you want you column to be not nullable (the restriction will be enforced by DB).

@NotNull is for validation.

Comment: Maybe you are referred to a really old version of Ebean but this is actually not correct on 2 counts.  1) com.avaje.ebean.validation.NotNull; ... no longer exists and instead you can use javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;   2) You do not need to use (@)Column(nullable = false) annotation if you have specified (@)NotNull. Ebean treats the existence of (@)NotNull as meaning the same as nullable=false so you don't need the (@)Column annotation in that case.  Cheers, Rob.

Answer (score 7):

Note that the accepted answer is no longer correct.

`com.avaje.ebean.validation.NotNull` no longer exists and instead you can use `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`

Secondly you **do not** need to specify `@Column(nullable = false)` if the @NotNull annotation is used.  Ebean takes the existence of @NotNull as meaning that the DB column is not null and handles that appropriately.